# VSCode: How to autocomplete only in JSDoc defined properties or classes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide, intellisense, jsdoc

I am using a framework, that generates automatically properties for classes and even classes can be generated by a define function.

The problem in Visual Studio Code is, that the autocompletion is not working if properties or whole classes are only defined by jsdoc. Or am I wrong? In Webstorm this works.

Example:

```
/**
 * @description
 * A Person
 *
 * @class
 */
function Person(name) {
    /**
     * @description
     * Name of the person
     * @property {String}
     */
    this.name = name;

    /**
     * @description
     * Another Name of the person
     * @property {String}
     */
    this.anotherName = name;

    /**
     * @description
     * Another Name of the person
     * @property {String}
     * @name Person#AndEvenMoreNames
     */
}

var oPerson = new Person("Peter");
oPerson.
```

Webstorm now enables autocompletion for all 3 properties, whereas Visual Studio Code only shows autocompletion for name and anotherName.

With classes defined only in JS it is the same...

Is my JSDoc wrong or the settings in VSCode?

Comment: did you solve this? i'm in a similar point

Comment: nope... and on github issues this is ignored... :(